# want to send and receive json data in php

Tags: php, json

As per application requirement, I am trying to develop two PHP which can communicate with each other via Json. I tried searching online but didn't found solution.

Can any one suggest me the right path for this?

I have data in mysql database, the converted data will be in json format as given below: (Also looking for code to get this data format via PHP-JSON object and array.)

```
{ "user" : [   
             { "firstName" : "Vignesh",  
               "lastName"  : "Prajapati",
               "age"       : 23,
               "email"     : ["vignesh@gmail.com","vignesh@yahoo.com"],
               "subject"   : ["English","Gujarati", "Hindi"]
             }, 

             { "firstName" : "Vaibhav",  
               "lastName"  : "Prajapati",
               "age"       : 19,
               "email"     : ["vaibhav@gmail.com","vaibhav@yahoo.com","vaibhav@aol.com"],
               "subject"   : ["English","Spanish", "Chinese","Sanskrit"]
             }
           ]
}
```

My Php code for sending Json data: (send.php)

```
<?php

$data = '    { "user" : [   
                 { "firstName" : "Vignesh",  
                   "lastName"  : "Prajapati",
                   "age"       : 23,
                   "email"     : ["vignesh@gmail.com","vignesh@yahoo.com"],
                   "subject"   : ["English","Gujarati", "Hindi"]
                 }, 

                 { "firstName" : "Vaibhav",  
                   "lastName"  : "Prajapati",
                   "age"       : 19,
                   "email"     : ["vaibhav@gmail.com","vaibhav@yahoo.com","vaibhav@aol.com"],
                   "subject"   : ["English","Spanish", "Chinese","Sanskrit"]
                 }
               ]
    } ';

$url_send ="http://localhost/rec.php";
$str_data = json_encode($data);

function sendPostData($url, $post){
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);  // Seems like good practice
  return $result;
}

echo " " . sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);

?>
```

My Php code for receiving Json data: (rec.php)

```
<?php

$json_input_data=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);

echo $json_input_data;


?>
```

Comment: If you already have data in json format so you shouldn't use `json_encode()` to encode it.

Comment: hi, @KristerAndersson, I have just manually written that json format data. Actually first I want data in that format and then I want to send.

Comment: @KristerAndersson, If I am wrong with my way then please suggest the direction.

Comment: Build a `user` object, fill it with an array of objects that contain individual user information en `json_encode()` the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your function to send header of JSON_DATA in post request

```
function sendPostData($url, $post){
 $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post))                                                                       
   );  
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);  // Seems like good practice
  return $result;
}
```

In file use

```
<?php

$json_input_data=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);

print_r( $json_input_data);


?>
```

As everyone said there is no need of `$str_data = json_encode($data);`,Since data is already in json.

Comment: Thanks @MADTerry, But if I have my data as $data = array('user' => array(
         array('firstName' => 'Vignesh', 'lastName' => 'Prajapati'),
         array('firstName' => 'Vaibhav', 'lastName' => 'Prajapati')
       ));  It is not working

Comment: Then you should use JSON_ENCODE

Comment: I used it, and it worked. But still I am not able to print that json elements. It gives error - Notice: Array to string conversion. on rec.php file.

Comment: print_r( $json_input_data); should be used if you are testing variable values.

Comment: Is there any function that will print all these values of array sequentially. (last help?)

Comment: @ViGnEsHPrAjApAtI What sequence you want ?

Comment: I want such that it print all of the elements of an array one by one with their attribute name.

Comment: print_r($vjson_input_data) does the same.

Comment: yes, Also I want to store all these element to database (on other server) so again I need to store them to separate variables. thats why I need this.

Comment: then you should use json_encode($json_input_data) that will return a string.

Answer (score 1):

Since you shouldn't use `json_encode` if the data already is in `json` format, change your code to something like:

```
$data = array('user' => array(
         array('firstName' => 'Vignesh', 'lastName' => 'Prajapati'),
         array('firstName' => 'Vaibhav', 'lastName' => 'Prajapati')
       ));
```

Of course you will need to add the other fields to the array as well.

Using `json_encode()` on the above data will return:

```
{
   "user" : [
     {
      "firstName" : "Vignesh",
      "lastName" : "Prajapati"
     },
     {
      "firstName" : "Vaibhav",
      "lastName" : "Prajapati"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Comment: Hey @Krister Andersson, thanks for your partial code it worked for me. ANd thanks for providing this understandings.!!

Comment: This right here is why I much prefer PHP5.4 when available. Square-bracket syntax is so much more readable when you're building a large, 4+ height tree as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that JSON means 'object notation', ie it's a way to describe an object in javascript. It's a great way to communicate at the network-level, but when you're in PHP you should be using the data structures that PHP is designed to use. Rather than work with JSON directly on either side, and especially as an alternative to a big JSON string, keep that data structured as an array and encode it right before sending. Your approach with curl is fine, though a bit custom - there's lots of nice routers that do a better job managing these sorts of requests (symfony is my favourite), but that's a separate issue.

e.g. instead of your big string, represent it as:

```
$data = 
    [ "user" => [   
                 [ "firstName" => "Vignesh",  
                   "lastName"  => "Prajapati",
                   "age"       => 23,
                   "email"     => ["vignesh@gmail.com","vignesh@yahoo.com"],
                   "subject"   => ["English","Gujarati", "Hindi"]
                 ]
```

etc..
When it comes time to send it to the other server, `json_encode` and go.

Comment: Hi Josh From Qaribou, Thanks for your message it helped me for understanding.!!